# What does it mean to have "thousands of containers"

Tags: kubernetes

I am starting on learning Containers and Kubernetes. When watching tutorials on Containers and Kubernetes, often the instructors says "You could have thousands of containers".

I am trying to understand how we can end up with thousands of containers?

After deploying my single container app, how thousands of container instances are created?

Comment: You have developed a thousand microservices for your new fantastically architectured app. You deploy them all, you have a thousand containers. You have developed five microservices for your simple but very popular app. You deploy each 200 times to scale the load, you have a thousand containers.

Comment: Aha. So its a manual process to create 1000 containers. 
I thought there is some sort of magic that turns my 1 container app into 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to GSerg suggestion

A cluster is a set of nodes running Kubernetes agents, managed by the control plane.You can scale your cluster by adding or removing nodes. The way you do this depends on how your cluster is deployed. The limit is 300000 containers.You can find this in this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/).

As per this [doc](https://www.netapp.com/devops-solutions/what-are-containers/)

> Containerized applications can get complicated, however. When in
> production, many might require hundreds to thousands of separate
> containers in production. This is where container runtime environments
> such as Docker benefit from the use of other tools to orchestrate or
> manage all the containers in operation.
>
> One of the most popular tools for this purpose is Kubernetes, a
> container orchestrator that recognizes multiple container runtime
> environments, including Docker.

The software that runs containers is called the container runtime. Kubernetes upholds compartment runtimes, for example, containerd, CRI-O, and some other execution of the Kubernetes CRI (Holder Runtime Point of interaction).

Usually, you can let your cluster choose a Pod's default container runtime. You can specify the RuntimeClass for a Pod to ensure that Kubernetes runs those containers using a specific container runtime if you need to use more than one container runtime in your cluster. Using RuntimeClass, you can also use the same container runtime to run multiple Pods with different settings.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your containerized app to Kubernetes using a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), they are meant to be *stateless*.

The good thing with *stateless* applications is that they are easy to scale out. You can use [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to automatically create more pods (instances) when you get increased traffic.

Note that the *Horizontal Pod Autoscaler* only scales out your *Pods*, you will eventually need to scale out your nodes too, but this must be handled by the underlying infrastructure, e.g. [Google Kubernetes Engine - Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) can do this for you.